# DXA 1.5 - Category / Keyword Metadata approach

Tags: dxa, keyword, metadata, dxa-1.5

We have a couple of Category/Keywords that are using a MetaData Schema, and the Tag class provided by DXA doesn't contain the metadata and looking at the source code I can't see a way to easily enrich it.

I was wondering what the best approach for this would be?

Long term it would be nice to see a similar approach to components where we can inherit tag and add any extra properties.

Comment: Looks like Will Price reported this already on github: https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-dotnet/issues/30 you may want to add your weight to this issue

Comment: Your wish is our command ;-). We're implementing this feature in DXA 1.7. See https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-dotnet/blob/develop/Sdl.Web.Common/Models/KeywordModel.cs

Answer (score 1):

With regards to your **I was wondering what the best approach for this would be?** question, it appears that even DD4T now recommend using the `Tridion.ContentDelivery.Taxonomies.TaxonomyFactory` rather than their original `DD4T.Factories.TaxonomyFactory` class:

https://github.com/dd4t/dynamic-delivery-4-tridion/blob/master/dotnet/DD4T.Factories/TaxonomyFactory.cs

Therefore, you may want to use an service layer within your application that accesses the Keyword details using `Tridion.ContentDelivery.Taxonomies.TaxonomyFactory` and supliments your model with this information.

You may want to look at the [Retrieving Keyword properties](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-695903BD-E969-4867-A248-D7124BF7069C) page in the online documentation for an example of using the `TaxonomyFactory` to get the Keyword Metadata.